# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una operación específica en cada iteración non en un bucle for? [Lua]

Tags: bucles, lua

No tengo nada de código base para esto, y no tengo idea de como hacerlo. Al principio se me ocurrió una tabla (local odds = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}) pero, esto llegaría a un límite, entonces ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo automatizado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la forma de hacerlo.

La operación % calcula el residuo de una división, si se divide la iteración entre dos y el residuo es cero, es par, pero, como queremos hacer esto con nones, se utiliza el operador lógico `not()` para indicar una acción contraria a la estipulada dentro de la misma.

```
local i = 0

for (bucle) do
if not(i % 2 = 0) then
--[Código Aquí]
i=i+1
else
--[Código Aquí]
i=i+1
end
end
```

Comment: Si bien la respuesta puede ser de utilidad, en la comunidad SO, no son bien recibidas este tipo de respuestas que no indican el porque ese código satisface la pregunta.Puedes editar la misma y completarla indicando claramente, porque esa solución cumple y en base a que, para que no recibas votos negativos, ya que estos te penalizan para comentar otras respuestas. Te invito a hacer el [tour] y [answer]

Comment: @Playerl ¿es esto una respuesta o una edición a la pregunta? Si es una respuesta, por favor, edítala para añadir más detalle (¿qué hace ese código? ¿cómo funciona? etc). Si es más información que debería ir en la pregunta, por favor edita la propia pregunta. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información y recomendaciones.